# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined" when doing a loop in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I am trying to loop over an array in the `render` method I get the following error :

```
Warning: React can't find the root component node for data-reactid value `.1zdr3j32tc0.0`. If you're seeing this message, it probably means that you've loaded two copies of React on the page. At this time, only a single copy of React can be loaded at a time.

/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js:715
    firstChildren[0] = deepestAncestor.firstChild;
                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined
    at Object.ReactMount.findComponentRoot (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js:715:39)
    at Object.ReactMount.findReactNodeByID (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js:679:23)
    at Object.getNode (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js:162:32)
    at Object.ReactDOMIDOperations.dangerouslyProcessChildrenUpdates (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactDOMIDOperations.js:83:42)
    at Object.wrapper [as processChildrenUpdates] (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:66:21)
    at processQueue (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:160:31)
    at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.updateChildren (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:334:13)
    at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._updateDOMChildren (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:871:12)
    at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.updateComponent (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:700:10)
    at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.receiveComponent (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:645:10)
    at Object.ReactReconciler.receiveComponent (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js:87:22)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:562:23)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:544:10)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:473:12)
    at [object Object].wrapper [as updateComponent] (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:66:21)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performUpdateIfNecessary (/home/anass/Dropbox/projects/code/elbotola/elbotola_react/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:421:12)
```

My component looks like this **LatestNews.jsx file**

```js
import React from 'react';
import request from 'superagent';
import moment from 'moment';

class LatestNews extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {articles: []};
    }

    fetch() {
        request
          .get('http://api.localhost.com/articles/')
          .end((err, res) => {
            if (res.ok) {
              this.setState({articles: res.body.results});
            }
          });

    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetch()
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.articles.map(post => {
                    return <span key={post.id}>Test</span>;
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LatestNews;
```

If this could help :

- This is done using [Server side rendering](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/server.js)
- The rendering happens. But after the error the server responds to no more requests.
- I'm using React-routing.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @Hacketo Fixed. Thanks. That typo slipped probably when I was formatting the code for SO. It's written correctly in code.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you do not have two copies of React included, as the first line of your stack trace warns?

Comment: `find ./ -name 'react'` returns only `./node_modules/react`. And my rendered HTML contains only one app.js file. Is there any other way I should check that too?

Comment: I suspect that by the time the callback is fired the component has already been unmounted and the resulting DOM pushed to the browser, but I'm not experienced enough with server-side React to confirm.

Comment: @Anass - Did you ever sort out the issue here? I am seeing similar intermittent behavior like this in my app.

Comment: @jerome Unfortunately not. I was using react-starter-kit's boilerplate. I had to get rid of it and start the project from scratch in order to grasp the ecosystem.

Comment: @Anass I have the same issue. The weird thing is, if I move my async data fetch from `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`, the error disappears. Unfortunately, I have no idea what that means. lol